# Django weasyPrint fontconfig error

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

I have an application that I need to get pdf files from so I opted for weasyprint but after installing with PIP I imported `import weasyprint` I got an error in terminal `OSError: ctype.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called fontconfig`

Then I tried to use `from weasyprint import HTML, CSS` `from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration` I still got the same error. Without writing any further codes the import statements is stuck on the error. I’m running the lates django and weasyprint as of October. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reinstall weasyprint with `python -m pip install weasyprint,` but first run

```
brew install python3 cairo pango gdk-pixbuf libffi
```

on mac osx